# ASP.NET MVC (2) NormalizeUrl Action Filter Attribute (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, normalization

Can someone verify the integrity of this chunk of code? I want to decorate the controllers with it so that it will normalize the url to either https and/or www. This is my second rewrite of the code because the first one tossed itself into an infinite redirect, but somehow I still think it's not quite there...

```
public class NormalizeUrl : ActionFilterAttribute {
    private bool ForceHttps = false;
    private bool ForceWww = false;

    public NormalizeUrl() {
    }

    public NormalizeUrl(
        bool ForceHttps,
        bool ForceWww) {
        this.ForceHttps = ForceHttps;
        this.ForceWww = ForceWww;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(
        ActionExecutingContext Context) {
        HttpRequestBase Request = Context.HttpContext.Request;
        HttpResponseBase Response = Context.HttpContext.Response;

        if (!Request.IsLocal) {
            Uri Uri;

            if (!Request.IsSecureConnection && ForceHttps) {
                if (ForceWww) {
                    Uri = new Uri(Uri.UriSchemeHttps + "://www." + Request.Url.Host.Replace("www.", string.Empty) + "/" + Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
                } else {
                    Uri = new Uri(Uri.UriSchemeHttps + "://" + Request.Url.Host.Replace("www.", string.Empty) + "/" + Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
                };
            } else if (!ForceHttps) {
                if (ForceWww) {
                    Uri = new Uri(Uri.UriSchemeHttp + "://www." + Request.Url.Host.Replace("www.", string.Empty) + "/" + Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
                } else {
                    Uri = Request.Url;
                };
            } else {
                Uri = Request.Url;
            };

            Response.RedirectPermanent(Uri.AbsoluteUri, true);
        };
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for a security assessment?

Comment: No, I'm looking for a verification (or suggestion on improvements) if the code will do what I want it to, which is to take `http://domain.com` and turn it into A) `http://www.domain.com`, B) `https://domain.com` or C) `https://www.domain.com` based on the arguments passed in by the controller decoration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, after breaking my site a couple of times, I came up with this stable code:

```
public class NormalizeUrl : ActionFilterAttribute {
    private bool ForceHttps = false;
    private bool ForceWww = false;

    public NormalizeUrl(
        bool ForceHttps,
        bool ForceWww) {
        this.ForceHttps = ForceHttps;
        this.ForceWww = ForceWww;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(
        ActionExecutingContext Context) {
        HttpRequestBase Request = Context.HttpContext.Request;
        HttpResponseBase Response = Context.HttpContext.Response;

        if (!Request.IsLocal) {
            if (!Request.IsSecureConnection && this.ForceHttps) {   //  http://domain.com OR http://www.domain.com
                if (this.ForceWww && !Request.Url.Host.Contains("www.")) {  //  http://domain.com
                    Response.RedirectPermanent(new Uri(Uri.UriSchemeHttps + "://www." + Request.Url.Host + Request.Url.AbsolutePath).AbsoluteUri, true);
                } else {    //  http://www.domain.com
                    Response.RedirectPermanent(new Uri(Uri.UriSchemeHttps + "://" + Request.Url.Host + Request.Url.AbsolutePath).AbsoluteUri, true);
                };
            } else {
                if (this.ForceWww && !Request.Url.Host.Contains("www.")) {  //  http://domain.com OR https://domain.com
                    Response.RedirectPermanent(new Uri(Request.Url.Scheme + "://www." + Request.Url.Host + Request.Url.AbsolutePath).AbsoluteUri, true);
                };
            };
        };
    }
}
```